# JMeter - How to implement "N users fire up N different queries simultaneously" scenario

Tags: jmeter

I have trouble implementing the following scenario and Google did't help - may be I am missing something obvious?

Scenario is :

- Step 1. 9 sesssions simultaneously running 3 different JDBC queries, i.e
  3*Q1,3*Q2,3*Q3 all starting and running at the same time

> Clarification: In the beginning of step 1, the following queries will start in 9 different sessions - Q1,Q1,Q1,Q2,Q2,Q2,Q3,Q3,Q3

- Step 2. 27 sessions like
  above (9 times each query)
- Step 3. 54 sessions (18 times each query)

Steps must run sequentially.

Comment: Hello,  question seems  ambiguous, do you want 3 sessions running 3 queries sequentially or 9 running 3 q sequentially or 9 simultaneously tunning 3 queries at the same time ?

Comment: It doesn't seem ambigous to me - it says 3 queries starting at the same time in 9 sessions, i.e simultaneously

Comment: Any news on that, is answer ok? If not did you find ?

Answer (score 0):

To do so:

Step 1)
3 thread groups, each one with 3 threads, each thread group calling a different Qi

Step2)
3 thread groups, each one with 9 threads, each thread group calling a different Qi with scheduler delayed so that it starts after step1 has finished

Step3)
Same as step2 with 18 threads and delayed so that it starts after step 2

But I must say I don't understand why you need such behaviour

Comment: Hi, I ended up just running 3 times the same Jmeter scenario with changed parameters. I didn't find a way to run this automagically with single scenario

Comment: Didn't you try my proposition ?

Comment: No, cause it didn't make sense, Step2) --- How am I supposed to know when it's finished? it doesn't have option to start after thread finishes, only at certain time...

Comment: It does make sense, but it was the first step. I wanted to be sure it was that you were expecting, you would have explained that, I would have completed answer. For example, to start after thread finishes, it could have been done with some Beanshell Sampler. I am not sure your solution is better :-) but if it's OK for you ....